# If will an IF statement return when we compare a NSString and a BOOL type variable

Tags: objective-c

In Objective-C, is
`if(abc && def)` allowed???
here `abc` is of `BOOL` type and `def` is of `NSString` type.
This condition is present in the code snippet I am going through. When will it return `YES` and when will it return `FALSE`?

Comment: The statement will be return YES only if, when abc != 0 means true AND def is not null even it pointing out garbage memory.

Comment: but how can we use a NSString and a BOOL together this way??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `if` statement will be true only if `abc` is unequal to `NO` and `def` is not `nil`.

The expression is equivalent to:

```
if (abc != 0 && def != 0) {
}
```

`abc` is not equal to `0` when it is unequal to `NO`. `def` is not equal to `0` when it is not `nil`.

Comment: Yes.. got it.. if abc is not equal to 0X00 or NO, and def is not equal to nil; then the result will be TRUE

Comment: The code would read a lot better written as if(abc == YES && dev != nil)

Comment: But that isn't the same. It needs to be `if (abc != NO && dev != nil)`.

Comment: @odyth but rmaddy sir think only he say's is right :) very nice sir rmaddy

Comment: @maddy (abc != no) is the same as (abc == YES).  if abc is yes then (YES != NO)  :)  The negative logic can be confusing when reading code quickly.  its easier to infer the positive then != NO.

Comment: @odyth That is only true if you can guarantee that `abc` is either `YES` or `NO`. If it is some other arbitrary value then the safest thing to do is to check for `!= NO` and not `== YES`.

Answer (score 0):

if (abc && def) {
}

this condition will return YES if abc is not ZERO and def is also not nil (means it contains some not nil value). in either case it will return NO.

i hope you will understand this.